# Source Control help! Branching individual pages TFS

Tags: .net, web-applications, version-control, tfs, branch

We use TFS at work purely for checking in work after release, and I've brought the idea of branching and merging into the office.
It's all gone well so far but now I've run into an issue that I can't figure out.

Normally, we have standalone applications (i.e. ProjectX).

I'll run a ProjectX Master branch, stage branch, and then development branches - easy peasy because ProjectX is relatively small.

Now I have a HUGE web application that essentially serves as the users entire OS - we give them access to this and not much else.

It has a wealth of components that all do different things and the project is a bit of a beast as you can imagine.

This BigProject may have say 12 different modules to it that are roughly the size of ProjectX.

The issue I'm having is, we are all mapped in TFS to the top level of BigProject, and don't have any branches of the entire thing.

What I would like to do, is make a branch of BigProject ModuleY, giving me time to improve ModuleY and have it nicely version controlled.

But when I branch from TFS it won't let me change the mapping of ModuleYBranch to what currently exists for ModuleY on my localhost.
This means I can't develop from localhost (it's pretty complex to get up and running). Instead I would have to develop in ModuleYBranch and then actively copy code over whenever I want to test.

The way I have it right now was actually setting up a brand new application in IIS, changing Oracle data to point to the right folder, and changing .htc files to get my localhost to point to ModuleYBranch, but if I want to get others to adopt this process thats too much work to set up (and I'm so close to converting them all!).

SHOULD I be branching the WHOLE of BigProject? 
I feel like there must be an easy way to pick out an individual subfolder and have some mappings moved around for development (and deployment to test-server).

Sorry if a bit too verbose but I'm really stuck here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes, branch at the uppermost node you can and always use that node.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer: While It is considered a bad practice that less to poor code quality you can branch any folder out.

The you will try to prevent you from don't anything this will, however the command line will.